# What's a solid technique for refactoring Cucumber steps?

Tags: cucumber

My step definitions have gone out of control.

They are everywhere! I probably have many steps that do the same thing.

I think it's even slowing my cucumber features from running quicker.

Help I need some good guidance!

What's the best way to control the beast of which we call "bad code".

I'm searching for a repeatable technique that I can use over and over again till my features and steps are crisp and clean again.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about the problems you have, more so than 'out of control' and 'they are everywhere'!  What problems are you actually experiencing?

Answer (score 5):

Without more specifics it's hard to give a good answer, so I'll expand this if you can add more detail to your question, but some general advice:

1. Organise your step files by the functional component of your application on which they operate, or the models that they deal with e.g. 'searching_steps', 'customer_steps', etc.  This should make it easier to find the available steps, and make it less likely that you'll inadvertently add a duplicate step.
2. If your step definitions contain a lot of logic, extract it into helper methods (described on the [cucumber wiki](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/A-Whole-New-World)).
3. If you have steps that are very similar, you can add parameters to your extracted helper methods, and re-use the extracted method between the similar steps.  This reduces duplication between steps.